# FFMPEG using AV_PIX_FMT_D3D11 gives "Error registering the input resource" from NVENC

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, direct3d11, nvenc

Input frames start on the GPU as `ID3D11Texture2D` pointers.

I encode them to H264 using FFMPEG + NVENC. NVENC works perfectly if I download the textures to CPU memory as format `AV_PIX_FMT_BGR0`, but I'd like to cut out the CPU texture download entirely, and pass the GPU memory pointer directly into the encoder in native format. I write frames like this:

```
int write_gpu_video_frame(ID3D11Texture2D* gpuTex, AVFormatContext* oc, OutputStream* ost) {
    AVFrame *hw_frame = ost->hw_frame;

    printf("gpuTex address = 0x%x\n", &gpuTex);

    hw_frame->data[0] = (uint8_t *) gpuTex;
    hw_frame->data[1] = (uint8_t *) (intptr_t) 0;
    hw_frame->pts     = ost->next_pts++;

    return write_frame(oc, ost->enc, ost->st, hw_frame);
    // write_frame is identical to sample code in ffmpeg repo
}
```

Running the code with this modification gives the following error:

```
gpuTex address = 0x4582f6d0
[h264_nvenc @ 00000191233e1bc0] Error registering an input resource: invalid call (9):
[h264_nvenc @ 00000191233e1bc0] Could not register an input HW frame
Error sending a frame to the encoder: Unknown error occurred
```

---

Here's some supplemental code used in setting up and configuring the hw context and encoder:

```
/* A few config flags */
#define ENABLE_NVENC TRUE
#define USE_D3D11 TRUE // Skip downloading textures to CPU memory and send it straight to NVENC
```

```
/* Init hardware frame context */
static int set_hwframe_ctx(AVCodecContext* ctx, AVBufferRef* hw_device_ctx) {
    AVBufferRef*       hw_frames_ref;
    AVHWFramesContext* frames_ctx = NULL;
    int                err        = 0;

    if (!(hw_frames_ref = av_hwframe_ctx_alloc(hw_device_ctx))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create HW frame context.\n");
        throw;
    }
    frames_ctx                    = (AVHWFramesContext*) (hw_frames_ref->data);
    frames_ctx->format            = AV_PIX_FMT_D3D11;
    frames_ctx->sw_format         = AV_PIX_FMT_NV12;
    frames_ctx->width             = STREAM_WIDTH;
    frames_ctx->height            = STREAM_HEIGHT;
    //frames_ctx->initial_pool_size = 20;
    if ((err = av_hwframe_ctx_init(hw_frames_ref)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize hw frame context. Error code: %s\n", av_err2str(err));
        av_buffer_unref(&hw_frames_ref);
        throw;
    }
    ctx->hw_frames_ctx = av_buffer_ref(hw_frames_ref);
    if (!ctx->hw_frames_ctx)
        err = AVERROR(ENOMEM);

    av_buffer_unref(&hw_frames_ref);
    return err;
}
```

```
/* Add an output stream. */
static void add_video_stream(
    OutputStream* ost,
    AVFormatContext* oc,
    const AVCodec** codec,
    enum AVCodecID  codec_id,
    int width,
    int height
) {
    AVCodecContext* c;
    int             i;
    bool            nvenc = false;

    /* find the encoder */
    if (ENABLE_NVENC) {
        printf("Getting nvenc encoder\n");
        *codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("h264_nvenc");
        nvenc  = true;
    }
    
    if (!ENABLE_NVENC || *codec == NULL) {
        printf("Getting standard encoder\n");
        avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
        nvenc = false;
    }
    if (!(*codec)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
                avcodec_get_name(codec_id));
        exit(1);
    }

    ost->st = avformat_new_stream(oc, NULL);
    if (!ost->st) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ost->st->id = oc->nb_streams - 1;
    c           = avcodec_alloc_context3(*codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not alloc an encoding context\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ost->enc = c;

    printf("Using video codec %s\n", avcodec_get_name(codec_id));

    c->codec_id = codec_id;
    c->bit_rate = 4000000;
    /* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
    c->width  = STREAM_WIDTH;
    c->height = STREAM_HEIGHT;
    /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
        * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
        * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
        * identical to 1. */
    ost->st->time_base = {1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE};
    c->time_base       = ost->st->time_base;
    c->gop_size = 12; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */

    if (nvenc && USE_D3D11) {
        const std::string hw_device_name = "d3d11va";
        AVHWDeviceType    device_type    = av_hwdevice_find_type_by_name(hw_device_name.c_str());

        // set up hw device context
        AVBufferRef *hw_device_ctx;
        // const char*  device = "0"; // Default GPU (may be integrated in the case of switchable graphics!)
        const char*  device = "1";
        ret = av_hwdevice_ctx_create(&hw_device_ctx, device_type, device, nullptr, 0);

        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not create hwdevice context; %s", av_err2str(ret));
        }

        set_hwframe_ctx(c, hw_device_ctx);
        c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_D3D11;
    } else if (nvenc && !USE_D3D11)
        c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_BGR0;
    else
        c->pix_fmt = STREAM_PIX_FMT;

    if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO) {
        /* just for testing, we also add B-frames */
        c->max_b_frames = 2;
    }

    if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO) {
        /* Needed to avoid using macroblocks in which some coeffs overflow.
            * This does not happen with normal video, it just happens here as
            * the motion of the chroma plane does not match the luma plane. */
        c->mb_decision = 2;
    }

    /* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
    if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        c->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}
```

Comment: Have you finally found a solution for this? I am with same issue right now, and nothing I am trying works 

Comment: @forlayo I'm gonna be honest. I eventually gave up on using the libav C libraries. Instead I used the FFmpeg CLI directly and read frames from stdout. I wrote a small library in Rust to help me do this: https://github.com/nathanbabcock/ffmpeg-sidecar.

Comment: Interesting plot twist.. and how it goes performance wise ? I am aiming for high framerate and low latency for live streaming

Comment: Believe it or not I found performance to be totally acceptable. Using ffmpeg I run video decoding with hardware acceleration (using `--hwaccel nvenc` or something equivalent). For my uses, video decoding was the largest bottleneck by an order of magnitude. Any performance impact from streaming over stdio pipes was trivial compared to the speed boost of the GPU. Especially when using Rust to move the buffers around.